# Multiple Random Matrices in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, random

How can I generate multiple different random matrixes of this sort:

```
rand_pix_l = np.random.randint(256, size=(5,5))
```

I would like to be able to predefine how many matrices I get that I will later loop over to create a meshgrid of this sort:

```
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1,rand_pix_l.shape[0]),np.linspace(0,1,rand_pix_l.shape[1]))
```

for each of the random matrices I generated.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: `rand_pix_l = np.random.randint(256, size=(5, 5, N))`? Avoid explicit looping when using numpy

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(#desired_number_of_matrices): 
    rand_pix_l = np.random.randint(256, size=(5,5))
    x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1,rand_pix_l.shape[0]), 
          np.linspace(0,1,rand_pix_l.shape[1]))
```